# Change Width of Image Tag In JSON Return via Javascript (Node.JS)

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, replace

I am basically getting a large block of HTML from blog posts returned as a JSON object and it includes images of all shapes and sizes (as well as other content). I need to parse the HTML and find all images to limit the width of the images in this feed to 300px or it will visually break the output container when I display it.

In a perfect world I can get the width of each image, compare it to 300px (checking if it is larger or smaller) and then pick which value to insert so images don't stretch.

I've tried a variety of solutions to no avail. I'm technically using Node.JS as this is all processed server-side but most JavaScript rules and RegEx functions apply so any help is appreciated.

Here is an example:

JSON:

```
         {
            "item": [
                {
                    "@attributes": {
                        "id": "dc2558524822540c332fba8e6162d2b9"
                    },
                    "link": {
                        "url": "",
                        "cta": "View"
                    },
                    "photo": {
                        "image": "http://website.com/images/studio/email/placeholder_image_750.png",
                        "width": "750"
                    },
                    "description": "Check out this image <a href="http://link.com"><img src="http://image.com" style="border:2px solid #ccc;" /></a> and one with a width <a href="http://link.com"><img src="http://image.com" width="700" align="left" /></a>",
                    "buttons": {
                        "button": [{
                            "cta": "Button",
                            "url": "#"
                       }]
                    }
                }
            ]
        };
```

I need it to output:

```
  'Check out this image <a href="http://link.com"><img src="http://image.com" width="300" style="border:2px solid #ccc;width:300px;height:auto;" /></a> and one with a width <a href="http://link.com"><img src="http://image.com" width="700" align="left" /></a>'
```

Everything I see is for PHP or jQuery. Any ideas?

**** UPDATE 3/31/2016 *******

Here is what I currently have that works fairly well:

```
        /* ##
          # Returns String
          #
          # Returns string elements parsed to display updated width
          #
          # Author: Mark Campbell / Thomas Reed
          # Date: 03/30/2015
          # Category: Utility
          # */

        updateWidthInString = function(options)
        {
            if (typeof options === 'undefined'){
            var options = {};
          }

          if (typeof options.maxImageWidth === 'undefined'){
            return '';
          }

          if (typeof options.elem_tags === 'undefined'){
            return '';
          }

          if (typeof options.ignoreWidth === 'undefined'){
            options.ignoreWidth == false;
          }

          var return_val = '';

            var elem_tags_length = options.elem_tags.length;

            // Loop over each item matching tag
            for (var i=0; i < elem_tags_length; i++) {

              // Check if we are ignoring current widths on items such as DIV and P tags. Remove width if so 
              if(!options.ignoreWidth){ 
                    // Update Width Attribute
                    options.elem_tags[i].setAttribute('width', options.maxImageWidth);
                } else {
                    options.elem_tags[i].removeAttribute('width');
                }

                // Continue Loop If Item Has No Style Attribute
                if(!options.elem_tags[i].hasAttribute('style')){
                     continue;
                }

                // Update Width Styles
                var elem_styles = options.elem_tags[i].getAttribute('style');                         // Get Style Tag
                var elem_styles_arr = elem_styles.replace(/(?:\r\n|\r|\n)/g, '').split(';');          // Split Off Styles
                var elem_styles_arr_length = elem_styles_arr.length;                                  // Get Length
                var has_max_width = false;
                var has_width = false;
                var elem_styles_updated = '';

                for (q = 0; q < elem_styles_arr_length; q++) {                                         // Loop Over Styles
                  var elem_style = elem_styles_arr[q].split(':');
                  elem_style[0] = elem_style[0].trim();

                  if(elem_style[0] == ''){
                    continue; 
                  }

                  // Check if we are ignoring current widths on items such as DIV and P tags 
                  if(options.ignoreWidth){                                                                    
                      if(elem_style[0] == 'width') {                              // Check if it is a width
                        continue;
                        has_width = true;
                      } else if (elem_style[0] == 'max-width') {                  // Check if it is a max-width
                        continue;
                        has_max_width = true;
                      } else if (elem_style[0] == 'min-width') {                  // Check if it is a min-width
                        continue;
                      }
                  } else {
                      if(elem_style[0] == 'width') {                              // Check if it is a width
                        var elem_style_value = parseInt(elem_style[1]);               
                        if(elem_style[1].indexOf('%') > -1 || (!isNaN(elem_style_value) && elem_style_value > parseInt(options.maxImageWidth)) ) {      
                          elem_style[1] = options.maxImageWidth + 'px';
                        }
                        has_width = true;
                      } else if (elem_style[0] == 'max-width') {                  // Check if it is a max-width
                        var elem_style_value = parseInt(elem_style[1]);
                        if(elem_style[1].indexOf('%') > -1 || (!isNaN(elem_style_value) && elem_style_value > parseInt(options.maxImageWidth))) {      
                            elem_style[1] = options.maxImageWidth + 'px';
                        }
                        has_max_width = true;
                      } else if (elem_style[0] == 'min-width') {                  // Check if it is a min-width
                        continue;
                      }
                  }

                  elem_styles_updated += elem_style[0] + ':' + elem_style[1] + ';';
                }

                // If we are ignoring widths than don't add these width properties
                if(!options.ignoreWidth){
                    if(!has_width) {
                    var imgDimensions = imgSize(options.elem_tags[i].getAttribute('src'));
                    var parsedImgWidthNative = parseInt(imgDimensions.width);
                            var parsedImgWidthMax = parseInt(options.maxImageWidth);
                            var determinedImgWidth = ((parsedImgWidthNative < parsedImgWidthMax) ? parsedImgWidthNative : parsedImgWidthMax);

                            if(parsedImgWidthNative > parsedImgWidthMax){
                                elem_styles_updated += 'width:'+options.maxImageWidth+'px;';
                                elem_styles_updated += 'max-width:'+parsedImgWidthNative+'px;';
                            }

                    }
                    /*
                    if(!has_width){
                      elem_styles_updated += 'width:'+options.maxImageWidth+'px;';
                    }

                    if(!has_max_width){
                      elem_styles_updated += 'max-width:'+options.maxImageWidth+'px;';
                    }
                    */
                }

                  // Check if the style tag is empty and remove it if so
                  if(elem_styles_updated == ''){
                      options.elem_tags[i].removeAttribute('style');
                  } else {   
                    options.elem_tags[i].setAttribute('style',elem_styles_updated);
                }

            }

            return return_val;
        }

        /* ##
          # Returns String
          #
          # Returns full HTML string with elements parsed to display updated width
          #
          # Author: Mark Campbell / Thomas Reed
          # Date: 03/30/2015
          # Category: Utility
          # */

        updateImageWidthInString = function(options)
        {

          if (typeof options === 'undefined'){
            var options = {};
          }

          if (typeof options.html === 'undefined'){
            return '';
          }

          if (typeof options.maxImageWidth === 'undefined'){
            return options.html;
          }

          var return_val = '';
            var doc = new dom().parseFromString(options.html);



          // Update IMG tags
            var elem_tags = doc.getElementsByTagName("img");
            if (typeof elem_tags !== 'undefined' && elem_tags.length > 0 ){
              options.elem_tags = elem_tags;
              updateWidthInString(options);
            }

          // Update DIV tags
          elem_tags = doc.getElementsByTagName("div");
            if (typeof elem_tags !== 'undefined' && elem_tags.length > 0 ){
              options.elem_tags = elem_tags;
              options.ignoreWidth = true;
              updateWidthInString(options);
            }

          // Update p tags
          elem_tags = doc.getElementsByTagName("p");
            if (typeof elem_tags !== 'undefined' && elem_tags.length > 0 ){
              options.elem_tags = elem_tags;
              options.ignoreWidth = true;
              updateWidthInString(options);
            }

          // Update table tags
          elem_tags = doc.getElementsByTagName("table");
            if (typeof elem_tags !== 'undefined' && elem_tags.length > 0 ){
              options.elem_tags = elem_tags;
              options.ignoreWidth = true;
              updateWidthInString(options);
          }  

          // Update td tags
          elem_tags = doc.getElementsByTagName("td");
            if (typeof elem_tags !== 'undefined' && elem_tags.length > 0 ){
              options.elem_tags = elem_tags;
              options.ignoreWidth = true;
              updateWidthInString(options);
          } 



            return_val = doc.toString();

            return doc;

        }
```

Comment: What you have there is a string, not JSON.

Comment: Why don't you add a css class that sets the width to 300? And if it is present in the <img> tag it won't matter because it will be more specific of a rule and applied.

Comment: Added the full JSON. Sorry if that was confusing. Also this is all done server side and outputs into Emails so you cant use CSS style sheets reliably.

Comment: @DigitalMC just include your css in the head between <style> tags. it will work.

Comment: @DigitalMC Do you need every <img> width to be set to 300? Or is that the minimum? Or just a width attribute present?

Comment: After prototyping I realized I would need to set a MAX width of 300px. So i need to check if it has a width greater than that and shrink it OR if the image is greater than that then shrink it. Make sense? The issue is the images are blowing out their container and  can't use % widths or stylesheets because of email.

Answer (score 1):

**Improved Answer**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

var myString =   'Check out this image <a href="http://link.com"><img src="http://image.com" width="300" style="border:2px solid #ccc;width:300px;height:auto;" /></a> and one with a width <a href="http://link.com"><img src="http://image.com" width="700" align="left" /></a>';
var match;
var source_array = [];
var end = /src="\S+"\s/g, cow;
while (( match = end.exec(cow)) != null) {
    alert("match found at " + match.index);
    alert(match);
    source_array.push(match); //src="http://myimagehere.jpg"
}

for(var i = 0; i < source_array.length; i++){
    console.log("Index:" + i + '='  + source_array[i]); // array of all the sources in the string
}
});
```

This will store all the src attributes of each image into an array. You can then use some generic image string to build out your images. For example:

```
for(var i = 0; i < source_array.length; i++){
    var myImage = "<img " + source_array[i] +" width='300' />";
    console.log(myImage);
}
```

**Output**

```js
    var cow = 'Check out this image <a href="http://link.com"><img src="http://image.com" width="300" style="border:2px solid #ccc;width:300px;height:auto;" /></a> and one with a width <a href="http://link.com"><img src="http://image.com" width="700" align="left" /></a>';

    var match;
    var source_array = [];
    var end = /src="\S+"\s/g, cow;
    while (( match = end.exec(cow)) != null) {
        alert("match found at " + match.index);
        alert(match);
        source_array.push(match);
    }

    for(var i = 0; i < source_array.length; i++){
        var myImage = "<img " + source_array[i] +" width='300' />";
        console.log(myImage);
    }
```

```html
<img src="http://image.com"  width='300' />
```

Comment: Thanks! How would I target the width with this? I can't use CSS because this HTML is going into an email and certain clients strip <style> tags altogether. I HAVE to inline the styles. I would also be alright grabbing the SRC attribute and replacing the entire <img> tag

Comment: @DigitalMC well the challenge will be first to look if there is a width attribute, and if you dont see one in the img tag you can add one. Your other alternative like you said would be just to store the src and then create your own img tag and use that stored src. The second option seems easier to me. I will get started on that. xD

Comment: Thanks @Radley! No need to get too crazy, I'll post what I am doing below. It is 98% there but may be pretty inefficient.

Comment: @DigitalMC - this was a good exercise for me so I don't mind. I hope this works for you!